# edit the Hotkey in VLC for AB Loop

Tags: vlc-media-player, hotkeys

I need to edit or change the AB Loop command in VLC . I know the hidden command is "SHIFT+l"
but it is not listed in HOTKEY editor for AB Loop, only LOOP/ALL/REPEAT is editable "l" hotkey.
I checked the "VLCRC" file. nothing there.
does anyone know where this info is stored? maybe a file I can edit?
I need it to be CTRL+l. The shift key does not work for my project.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no hotkey for the AB Loop (see [here](https://www.vlchelp.com/vlc-media-player-shortcuts/) and [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/vlc-media-player-windows-shortcuts/)). That's why you can't locate it. Only the button on when Advanced controls is enabled allows to use it.

If you have Mac, you can set up a system level shortcut as described [here](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/4498):

> However I'm able to set a system level shortcut of my choice in System Preferences.app at Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts by clicking the + symbol and choosing VLC.app as the Application and A→B Loop as the Menu Title.

Comment: yes there is a HotKey for AB loop it's SHift+l it's a hidden secret. i just want to edit it I want to change to CTRL key + l